# Error when using insert CTE

Tags: sql-server

I am receiving the following error in SQL Server 2012:

> Invalid object name 'Libraries'.

Is there a way to modify the syntax so I don't have to use table variables? The problem arises at the end of the code where I placed the into statement.

Below is the code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
declare @level int = 0

DECLARE @DataLibraryName VARCHAR(500)
SET @DataLibraryName = 'FN_PerfSalesChargeFeeReplacementText'; 

IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@DataLibraryName)) = '' 
     SET @DataLibraryName = null; 

WITH DataLibraryRaw AS 
( 
    SELECT 
       *
       ,CAST(CAST(dataLibraryXML AS NTEXT) AS XML) dataLibraryXMLData 
       ,datasource_name dataLibraryName 
    FROM 
       tblrpt_datascript 
    --WHERE datasource_type = 'DLMERGE' 
), 
DataLibraryDep AS
( 
   SELECT 
      dataLibraryName 
      ,dataLibraryXMLData.query('//SourceSpecification') [SourceSpecification] 
   FROM 
      DataLibraryRaw 
), 
DependenciesXML AS
( 
    SELECT 
       dataLibraryName 
       ,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([SourceSpecification] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '#', '<item>#'), '}', '}</item>') AS XML) AS dataLibraryXMLData 
    FROM 
       DataLibraryDep 
), 
DataLibraries AS 
( 
   SELECT 
      dataLibraryName 
      ,d.i.query('.').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') dependDataLibrary 
   FROM 
      DependenciesXML dx 
   CROSS APPLY 
      dataLibraryXMLData.nodes('//item') AS d(i) 
), 
Libraries AS 
( 
    SELECT 
       dataLibraryName parentDL 
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([dependDataLibrary], CHARINDEX('=', [dependDataLibrary] ,1)+1 ,CHARINDEX('{', [dependDataLibrary], 1)-(CHARINDEX('=', [dependDataLibrary] ,1)+1)))) childDL 
    FROM 
       DataLibraries 
),
RecursiveData AS 
( 
    SELECT 
       *, 0 AS LEVEL 
    FROM 
       Libraries 
    WHERE 
       parentDL = IsNull(@DataLibraryName, parentDL) 
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveData 

---- Recursive member definition

insert RecursiveData 
   SELECT 
       m.parentDL, m.childDL, 
       @level + 1 
   FROM 
       Libraries m 
   INNER JOIN 
       RecursiveData r ON r.childDL = m.parentDL AND r.level = @level
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All those CTE's (including `Libraries`) are only valid for the **one, single next statement** (`SELECT * FROM RecursiveData`) - you cannot refer to the CTE's later on

Answer (score 0):

Based on your script above, the problem is that you are doing a select from your CTE:

`SELECT * FROM RecursiveData`

THEN doing your insert:

```
insert RecursiveData 
SELECT m.parentDL, m.childDL, 
@level + 1 
FROM Libraries m 
INNER JOIN RecursiveData r 
ON r.childDL = m.parentDL and r.level = @level
```

You can't reference a CTE after the statement that uses it, so your insert will always fail so long as the `SELECT *` statement is there. However, the other issue is that you appear to be trying to insert into your last CTE, RecursiveData, which also wouldn't work the way you expect.

It looks like your last section of code before your insert should be:

```
,RecursiveData AS (
    SELECT ParentDL, ChildDL, 0 AS LEVEL 
    FROM Libraries 
    WHERE parentDL = IsNull(@DataLibraryName, parentDL) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l.PARENTDL, l.CHILDDL, r.LEVEL + 1
    FROM Libraries l
    JOIN RecursiveData r ON r.CHILDDL = l.PARENTDL
    )
    SELECT * FROM RecursiveData
```

And you'd want to leave the insert off entirely (or insert it into whatever table you need).

Comment: So I actually want the insert because it will add a second recursive level. Is it possible to format given the current code?

Comment: The example I give above should help you build the recursive level. It's how to build a recursive CTE. You can get a more thorough explanation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx